# React Install problem. Node js install but React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
C:\Users\Asus\OneDrive\Desktop\react.js>npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-07T11_41_19_084Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\Asus\OneDrive\Desktop\react.js>node -v
v18.17.0

C:\Users\Asus\OneDrive\Desktop\react.js>npm -v
9.6.7

C:\Users\Asus\OneDrive\Desktop\react.js>
```

[image]
please help me for creating react app

Comment: Tangential: if that OneDrive is syncing get ready for lots of traffic—not sure you really want node_modules to sync. If you already have that turned off nvm 